# Entity Reference view field - results of the view don't display

Tags: views, entities

I am using [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module and I have a view displaying the group members.

In a content type, I have a field where I want the members to appear in a select list so I can select one when creating the node.

**Example:**

```
**Name of the company**

list: member 1, member 2, member 3 etc
```

- For that I used the [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module and added a field. In the field I chose `Group members` and selected the view that displays all members.
- But when I am about to add a node, the field displays only two options, and I belive it's the two last created members.
- If I go to **www.mysite.com/name-of-the-view** I can see: member 1, member 2, member 3, member 4
- If I select the field with the exact same view I can only see member 3, member 4.

I don't know how to solve this. The view looks just fine...

Can anyone please help? Thanks

This is the view:

[image]

This is how it looks like in the page:

[image]

This is the field (as you can see with only two members):

[image]

Comment: Can you post an export, or even a screenshot of your view?

Comment: What do you have in the Contextual Filter User UID settings?

Comment: Id say its an issue with the Contextual Filter, start by removing it and checking that all users show up

Comment: Yes, I removed the contextual filter (http://imgur.com/a/Wlyj8) and this is what happened: http://imgur.com/a/tZlqo Only 2 appear as before but this time they are repeated...

Comment: And since I am logged in with user A, I should be able to see only the members of my group: A1, A2 and A3

Comment: Hi, do you have any ideas to help me on this? Thanks